# Why does bind (socket binding) method generate a file in the current directory?

Tags: c, sockets, process

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main()
{

int sock;
    struct sockaddr sock_name = {AF_UNIX, "Fred"};
    socklen_t len=sizeof(struct sockaddr)+5;


    if( (sock=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0)) ==-1)
    {
        printf("error creating socket");
        return -1;
    }

    if( bind(sock,&sock_name,len) != 0 )
    {

        printf("socket bind error");
        return -1;
    }

    close(sock);


return 0;
}
```

After the first run, this program keeps reporting binding error. I tried to change the name of the sockaddr. It works again. But after changing it back to "Fred" (in this case), the error continues. Is something being stored in memory I didn't clear? Why does this happen and how could I fix it?

I guess I have found the problem. After the first run, I find a file named "Fred" in the current directory. I removed the file and my program worked again. Why does bind method generate a file in the current directory?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a generic `sockaddr` when you should be setting up a `sockaddr_un`? (and did not the compiler warning about casting a `const char*` to `int` flag a hint something may be wrong?

Comment: This is the sample code my teacher give us. GCC no warnings.

Comment: Run the code and you will see a file generated in the current directory. Removing the file solves the problem.

Comment: Ok. I understand. the setup is still wrong, but that doesn't matter to your problem. every use of AF_UNIX i've ever seen on the server-side performs an `unlink()` of the path-var once the socket is closed. It would appear that is the piece you're missing. I.e. `unlink("Fred")` once the socket closes successfully should do it. [**This example**](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/rzab6/xafunixsrv.htm) is probably the best one I can find on setting up an AF_UNIX socket correctly. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. I should have unlinked the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used with Unix domain sockets, `bind(2)` will create a special file at the specified path. This file identifies the socket in much the same way a host and port identify a TCP or UDP socket. Just like you can't call `bind` twice to associate two different sockets with a given host and port*, you can't associate more than one Unix socket

But why doesn't the file disappear when you call `close(2)`? After all, closing a TCP socket makes the host and port it was bound to available for other sockets.**

That's a good question, and the short answer is, it just doesn't.

So it's customary (at least in example code) to call `unlink(2)` prior to binding.  The Unix domain socket section of [Beej's IPC guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage) has a nice [example](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html#unixsockserv) of this.

*With versions of the Linux kernel >= 3.9, this isn't [exactly  true](http://lwn.net/Articles/542629/).

**After `TIME_WAIT` or immediately if you use the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option.

**EDIT**

You said this is your teacher's code, but I suggest that you replace your `printf` calls with `perror`:

```
if( bind(sock,&sock_name,len) != 0 )
{

    perror("socket bind error");
    return -1;
}
```

...which will print out a human-readable representation of the real problem encountered by `bind(2)`:

```
$ ./your-example-executable
$ ./your-example-executable 
socket bind error: Address already in use
```

Programming doesn't have to be so inscrutable!

Answer (score 0):

When you successfully open a socket, it stays open until it is closed (even if your program terminates).

It appears that the question code is not closing the socket in the event of an (such as the failure of bind()).

Two processes cannot generally open the same socket.

Each time the code is executed, it is a new process, attempting to open the same socket.

The code needs a better scheme to handle errors.

This is how I would do it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MY_FALSE (0)
#define MY_TRUE  (-1)

int main()
   {
   int rCode=0;
   int sock = (-1);
   char *socketFile = "Fred");
   struct sockaddr sock_name = {AF_UNIX, socketFile};
   socklen_t len=sizeof(struct sockaddr)+5;
   int bound = MY_FALSE;

   if((sock=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0)) ==-1)
      {
      printf("error creating socket");
      rCode=(-1);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   if( bind(sock,&sock_name,len) != 0 )
      {
      printf("socket bind error");
      rCode=(-1);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }
   bound=MY_TRUE;
```

This single 'cleanup' area can be used to free allocated memory, close sockets & files, etc.

```
CLEANUP:

   if((-1) != sock)
       close(sock);

   if(bound)
       unlink(socketFile);

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any idea why a file name "Fred" is generated in the current directory after running this code?

Comment: Yes; I believe I have an idea.  Examine it closely.  It is not a 'regular' file.  It is a 'lingering' file system entry that is associated with the "Local Unix" socket.  (mostly a filesystem placeholder from your bind() call).

Comment: In your code, where you put the the string "Fred", is actually where you can specify a complete path; such as "/tmp/Fred" or similar.  Since there was no '/' character in the path, bind() assumed the current working directory is where you wanted to place it.